# Cell/row formatting in Oracle TableRenderDemo

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer

Ok, first let me say that I'm returning to programming after quite a few years away. Things have changed quite a bit in the mean time (IDEs, OO) and I'm starting to program in Java for the first time.

I need to build a GUI front end and am currently struggling with JTables, tableModels and Renderers.

I'm currently working my way through the Oracle TableRenderDemo trying to understand exactly what it's doing and am getting a bit stuck.

I suspect I'll probably be adding to this post, but for now...

What I don't understand is when first run, why the whole row is green for John and Jane, but when I click the Vegetarian clickBox for either of them only the comboBox cell changes colour and not the whole row?

Please bear in mind that I'm really new to all this Java stuff and probably need an explanation in very simple terms.

Many thanks,

Gary

Here's the code... (thanks)
    package com.novartis.adhoc.view;

```
/*
 * TableRenderDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

/**
 * TableRenderDemo is just like TableDemo, except that it explicitly initializes
 * column sizes and it uses a combo box as an editor for the Sport column.
 */
public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel())
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                    int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);

                // Color row based on a cell value
                if ((Boolean) getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 4)) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    c.setBackground(getBackground());
                }
                return c;
            }
        };

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        // Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // Set up column sizes.
        initColumnSizes(table);

        // Fiddle with the Sport column's cell editors/renderers.
        setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));

        // Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    /*
     * This method picks good column sizes. If all column heads are wider than
     * the column's cells' contents, then you can just use
     * column.sizeWidthToFit().
     */
    private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
        MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();
        TableColumn column = null;
        Component comp = null;
        int headerWidth = 0;
        int cellWidth = 0;
        Object[] longValues = model.longValues;
        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

            comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(null,
                    column.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
            headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            comp = table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(i))
                    .getTableCellRendererComponent(table, longValues[i], false, false, 0, i);
            cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Initializing width of column " + i + ". "
                        + "headerWidth = " + headerWidth + "; cellWidth = "
                        + cellWidth);
            }

            column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, cellWidth));
        }
    }

    public void setUpSportColumn(JTable table, TableColumn sportColumn) {
        // Set up the editor for the sport cells.
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
        comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
        comboBox.addItem("Knitting");
        comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
        comboBox.addItem("Pool");
        comboBox.addItem("None of the above");
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

        // Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
        sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport",
                "# of Years", "Vegetarian" };
        private Object[][] data = {
                { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5),
                        new Boolean(false) },
                { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) },
                { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2),
                        new Boolean(false) },
                { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20),
                        new Boolean(true) },
                { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false) } };
        public final Object[] longValues = { "Jane", "Kathy",
                "None of the above", new Integer(20), Boolean.TRUE };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/ editor for
         * each cell. If we didn't implement this method, then the last column
         * would contain text ("true"/"false"), rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class<? extends Object> getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            // Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            // no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's data can
         * change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                        + " to " + value + " (an instance of "
                        + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create and set up the content pane.
        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

---

OK, so I really wanted to add to the post rather than edit the original one, but I can't work out how to do it (feeling really thick at the moment). Anyhow I'm looking at the following section at the moment...

```
TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

    comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                         null, column.getHeaderValue(),
                         false, false, 0, 0);
    headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;

    comp = table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(i)).
                     getTableCellRendererComponent(
                         table, longValues[i],
                         false, false, 0, i);
    cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
}
```

So am I correct in assuming from this that the header has a different renderer from the rest of the table?

Also, I don't get the parameters for headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent... table = null, row = 0, column = 0. What's going on here?

Also, if column.getHeaderValue() returns the object in the header for column i, why can't we just say:

```
comp = column.getHeaderValue();
headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
```

Thanks,

Gary

Comment: Try different [Look & Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) implementations to see the effect.

Comment: Render's are used to render multiple cells (usually for the same column), if you don't reconfigure them completely, they carry over the state from one cell to another.  Post a runnable example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing is the code was supplied to me by a colleague (I thought it was the exact code off the Oracle web site), but no, he'd been playing with it.

Anyhow...

> What I don't understand is when first run, why the whole row is green
>   for John and Jane, but when I click the Vegetarian clickBox for either
>   of them only the comboBox cell changes colour and not the whole row?

I think I've figured out why this happened - The following code is executed for each cell in the row:

```
if ((Boolean) getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 4)) {
    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
} else {
    c.setBackground(getBackground());
```

So, when the table is first drawn... for the first column, it checks the value in column 4 and if it's 'True' it sets the cell in column 0 green (and columns 1-3). However, when the value in column 4 is changed to 'False', the renderer hasn't run on the cell in column 0 (etc.), so it doesn't know to do this check again and hence the colour can't change for the other columns.

Anyhow, I've got around this by...

```
if ((Boolean) getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 4)) {
    c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    repaint();
} else {
    c.setBackground(getBackground());
```

Getting there!

Comment: Odd... This works exactly as I would have hoped, but I don't understand why it should work correctly when I set 'Vegetarian' to false - the code doesn't do a repaint, but it sets all of the cell backgrounds to white.
Actually, this raises another question, if the bacground is green, why does c.setBackground(getBackground()) set it to white? Surely getBackground() returns green and the c.setBackground just sets it to green again?